# SN1 products for (1S,2R,4R)-1-chloro-2,4-dimethylcyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

#### Question

> [image: (1S,2R,4R)-1-chloro-2,4-dimethylcyclohexane]
>
> Total number of S<sub>N</sub>1 products of given compound are
>
> A) $3$
>
> B) $4$
>
> C) $5$
>
> D) $6$

#### Answer

> (C) $5$

#### My attempt

I can find only $4$ products. The two stereoisomers formed from the carbocation, when chlorine leaves, and two stereoisomers formed when the hydrogen from the neighbouring carbon centre migrates (i.e. rearrangement occurs) and nucleophilic attack takes place from both sides.

I still am unable to find the fifth product. Moreover, I don't suppose the $\ce{-CH3}$ opposite to the point where the carbocation forms can interfere with the product. What would be the fifth product?

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/a-concise-template-for-homework-questions. When asking problem statements, could you try to conform to this template? You seem to be someone who would stick through SE for an extended period of time and we would be glad to keep it that way

Comment: @Safdar I started actively today in this forum. Hence I am unaware about the etiquette. I shall keep the code of questioning in mind.

Comment: For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Is there no other information given in this question?

Comment: I don't think a 5th product should be possible here

Comment: @Safdar No, nothing more is provided in the question.

Comment: A very weird proposition, a hydride shift to the other side since the number of alpha hydrogens increases from 3 to 4, the other shift is more stable since it goes from 3 to 7, but still is possible. This makes the answer 6 though. @YusufHasan

Comment: Are stereoisomers considered? (I'm guessing they are)

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb they have to be since you only have 3 possible locations for the carbocation to achieve.

Comment: Since total number of products is more than 2, we have to counter initial secondary carbocation survived enough time to give two of other products. If that so, 1,2-hydride transfer can happen in both side to give the fifth (and sixth?) product. If the answer is expected to be number of theoretical products, then there are a lot of possibilities to have more than 5 products. That means, the question is misleading.

Comment: @Safdar Yeah, if we do the shift towards the other side, I guess we can end up with 6(not 5) products. As Mathew says, this is probably a misleading question

Comment: This is a bad question. The nucleophile should be specified. What if we used a mildly nucleophilic, non-basic source of hydride?

Comment: @Safdar I thought about the hidride shift proposition too. But, the ring strain generated during migration to opposite side will be immense.

Comment: Yes, maybe its an incomplete question or everything is not sufficiently provided.